# Oracle SQL - Find origin ID of autoincrement column

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery, oracle-sqldeveloper

There's a table on my ERP database that has data about certain events. It has the start date, end date and a column shows if the event is a continuation of a previous one (sequential_id references unique_id). Here's an example:

| unique_id | start_date | end_date | sequential_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-15 |  |
| 002 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-16 | 001 |
| 003 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-17 | 002 |
| 004 | 2021-03-10 | 2021-03-11 |  |
| 005 | 2021-03-19 |  |  |

In the example above, rows 001, 002 and 003 are all part of the same event, and 004/005 are unique events, with no sequences. How can I group the data in a way that the output is like this:

| origin_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-17 |
| 004 | 2021-03-10 | 2021-03-11 |
| 005 | 2021-03-19 |  |

I've tried using group by, but due to sequential_id being auto incremental, it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use modern `match_recognize` which is an optimal solution for such tasks:

[Pattern Recognition With MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e12048/pattern_recog.htm)

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=22b669da5eba92e112e7f44d316842fd)

```sql
select *
from t
match_recognize(
  measures 
     first(unique_id) start_unique_id,
     first(start_date) start_date,
     last(end_date) end_date
  pattern (strt nxt*)
  define nxt as sequential_id=prev(unique_id)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use hierarchical query for this:

> ```
> with a (unique_id, start_date, end_date, sequential_id) as (
>   select '001', date '2021-01-01', date '2021-01-15', null  from dual union all
>   select '002', date '2021-02-01', date '2021-02-16', '001' from dual union all
>   select '003', date '2021-03-01', date '2021-03-17', '002' from dual union all
>   select '004', date '2021-03-10', date '2021-03-11',  null from dual union all
>   select '005', date '2021-03-19', null, null               from dual
> )
> , b as (
>   select
>     connect_by_root(unique_id) as unique_id
>     , connect_by_root(start_date) as start_date
>     , end_date
>     , connect_by_isleaf as l
>   from a
>   start with sequential_id is null
>   connect by prior unique_id = sequential_id
> )
> select
>   unique_id
>   , start_date
>   , end_date
> from b
> where l = 1
> order by 1 asc
> ```
>
> ```
> UNIQUE_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE 
> :-------- | :--------- | :--------
> 001       | 01-JAN-21  | 17-MAR-21
> 004       | 10-MAR-21  | 11-MAR-21
> 005       | 19-MAR-21  | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0f26ba3346dc98e6ac9704b9d9e77b8e)*

Answer (score 1):

This is a graph-walking problem, so you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte (unique_id, start_date, end_date, start_unique_id) as (
      select unique_id, start_date, end_date, unique_id
      from t
      where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t.sequential_id = t2.unique_id)
      union all
      select t.unique_id, t.start_date, t.end_date, cte.start_unique_id
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.unique_id = t.sequential_id
     )
select start_unique_id, min(start_date), max(end_date)
from cte
group by start_Unique_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=83d9c31f978b6c3028fc8dd7aebb62e0) is a db<>fiddle.